# c++ finding memory leak

Tags: c++, valgrind, waf

I am trying to run valgrind with waf. The command is ./waf --command-template="valgrind %s" --run program-name.

I receive an internal error for valgrind. What else can I try if even valgrind fails ?

```
--6446-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--6446-- si_code=80;  Faulting address: 0x0;  sp: 0x40b3c9df0

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal
==6446==    at 0x38058236: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6446==    by 0x38021ADC: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6446==    by 0x38021CCD: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6446==    by 0x380902A7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6446==    by 0x3809F7D5: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6446==    by 0x3809FA5A: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6446==    by 0x380BBEAD: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==6446==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???
==6446==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???
==6446==    by 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEE: ???
```

Comment: See the [list of Valgrind bugs](https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=product%3Avalgrind) and submit a new one if necessary.

Comment: do you have some really optimized libraries/code in your program?  I got similar errors when I tried to run valgrind on code that linked to  Intel Performance Primitives which uses some fancy memory/cpu instructions tricks under the hood to eek out a bit more speed.

Comment: Much of the code isn't mine so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried it for a long time but you can use the Boehm GC to detect leaks in C/C++ code.

http://www.hboehm.info/gc/leak.html